# Override Detail template for a Content Type with url alternate in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Does anyone know if it's possible to override  the DisplayType template for a ContentType using the an url alternate template? For example, is it possible to override the template:
Content-Page.Detail.cshtml with Content-url-homepage-Page.Detail.cshtml? After playing around a bit, it does not seem so. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to achive is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? The content that is shown on any URL will be shown either in `detail` or in `summary` mode, it can't be both for the same content on the same URL..

Answer (score 0):

You can view all available alternates for a shape by enabling the 'Shape Tracing' feature and viewing the list of alternates e.g. http://devhammer.net/blog/Customize-Orchard-CMS-with-Designer-Tools

For example on the main content item of the homepage I get out of the box:

```
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-url-homepage.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content.Detail.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-Page.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-10.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-Page.Detail.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-10.Detail.cshtml
```

Your options are to add or extend existing alternate factories such as Orchard.DesignerTools.Services.UrlAlternatesFactory e.g.

```
// appends [ShapeType]__url__[Url]_[DisplayType] alternates
context.ShapeMetadata.Alternates = _urlAlternates.Value.Select(url => 
    context.ShapeMetadata.Type + "__url__" + url + "_" + 
        context.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType)
        .Union(context.ShapeMetadata.Alternates)
        .ToList();
```

This will give you the alternate
    ~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-url-homepage.Detail.cshtml

or to use one of the existing alternates such as

```
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content-10.Detail.cshtml
```

Which looks like it might suit your purposes (to me using the id is not as clean as using the url)

I also tried adjusting the feature priority of the 'Url Alternates' feature so that the url alternates are appended to all the other existing alternates as it appears from the code was intended, but as far as I can see this is not working or otherwise not supported.